# twig variable in ng-show

Tags: angularjs, twig

There is a way to write:

```
<th ng-show=" {{ 'item._type' }}  != null"> Type</th>
```

and the twig part:

```
{% include "@fileName" with item: 'entity' %}
```

Right now it gives me the error:

```
 Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of statement block" expected).
```

Comment: {% include "@fileName" with { item: 'entity' } %}